# Removing Range Hood Bolts / Screws

Tags: range-hood

My range hood isn't working properly.  When I turn it on it sounds like it the motor is trying to turn, and I can see the fan spinning very slowly.  I removed and cleaned the grease filters, but that didn't help.  I'm guessing there is just some grease build up in the motor / fan blades that I need to clean out.  I have no idea how old the range hood is, but it's probably at least 10 years old.  It may not have been cleaned very often since it was first installed by the previous home owners.

To clean the fan blades I need to remove the housing by unscrewing a lot of screws.  It seems like the best way to do that is to remove the motor housing from the range hood, which would give me more space to maneuver a screw driver.  The problem is that the 4 attachment points for the housing have a weird type of screw / bolt that I've never seen before.  There is a slot in the end of the thread, and the nut is some weird square piece of metal.  It almost looks like a square clip overtop of something else?  I've never seen anything like this before.  I tried turning it with some pliers, and it didn't want to budge.  Maybe I just need to use a flat head screwdriver?  Does anybody recognize this?

Before I break something I thought I'd ask if anybody has seen this before?  Everything I see online about range hoods always has just regular screws.  It's hard to get a good picture since there isn't a lot of space and the breaker for the hood  and lights is turned off, but take a look.

[image: image of a bolt or screw in a range hood]

Comment: A nut/holder should be tight to the threads.  The square looks more like a placement/guide.  Have you tried turning the stud with a screwdriver?

Comment: The photo isn't very helpful, what does that screw-thing shown have to do with the fan motor? Most range hoods would have a label somewhere stating make and model #. Most range hood fan motors I've worked on just required removing 2 or 3 screws/bolts from the supporting bracket(s), no housings to remove except wiring compartment covers.

Comment: Yes, fan access is usually straightforward. On mine, loosen 3 screws and rotate the ring holding the fan motor. Takes about 30 seconds after the first time figuring out how it was held in. Don't go tearing more apart than you actually need to.

Comment: This may be a Dzus fastener or an equivalent 1/4 turn fastener. Try turning counterclockwise with a slotted screwdriver. If it stops after 1/4 turn, do the same to all four and then pull the panel off.